# can I think framework as class template in c++?

Tags: c++, software-design

After reading some posts online, even though they explain it using non-coding way, I still feel unclear about this. They explain it using some examples in our real life.

Could you please explain it in coding way? 
What is framework?
My understand is that it is pretty much like class template in c++.

```
template <typename T> class Reader {
// code details
}
```

So, if we want the reader to read newspaper, we instantiate `Reader<NewsPaper>` or `Reader<ScaryBook>`

Am I right? Or what's wrong if understanding framework this way?

Thank you!

Comment: A template is a template. A template might be part of a library, may be, even a header-only library. I wouldn't call one template a framework. Your template sample code even lacks details whether it's a class template or a function template (or even something else).

Comment: Recalling [framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework), you could understand [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) as framework. It forces to write an application in a manner where custom code may create a set of nested widgets and reacting on events (or signals) delivered from Qts provided main loop.

Comment: Further reading [Overloads and templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/) and [An Idiot's Guide to C++ Templates - Part 1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1) (no offense, that is the name of the article...)

Comment: From wiki: Frameworks have key distinguishing features: inversion of control, extensibility, non-modifiable framework code.    Class templates have similar properties.  You can instantiate the template, but you have no control over the code in template. As for extensibility, ```Reader<NewsPaper>``` is a class, you could inherit from it.   Finally, non-modifiable because user only instantiate the template.      So, why you feel that they are completely different thing. For me, I feel that they are pretty similar for the above reason.

Comment: A framework is *much much larger* than an single class template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me term "framework" doesn't suit C/C++ world well. Traditionally external modules in these languages are named "libraries" or "libs" (this naming is used in *nix systems as well when downloading them from web repository). Even though there might be some different interpretation for this terms, they are generally about the same thing (especially for C/C++ applications).

External library is a piece of code which performs some functionality. When dealing with big libraries (like one for creating, networking, image processing, multi-threading etc.) programmer has to follow some workflow proposed by it. **You may think of library as a *"black box"*. It provides you interface (rules how to use it: input and output params, error codes etc.) but you don't know what is inside and generally don't need it.**

Depending on solved problem library may be (or not) extensible. Library for reading various audio formats may not provide way to create readers for new audio formats but networking library should provide functionality to create user-defined networking protocols.

And template is a variadic piece of code. One backbone code which suits different datatypes. It's a powerful tool both for applications design and performance (which is commonly used in libraries as well for that reasons).